# Wget regex fails getting files over ftp

Tags: regular-expression, wget

From the site

> ftp://atmos.nmsu.edu/PDS/data/mslrem_1001/DATA/

I want to download the files ending in `.TAB` and have in the name RMD for all the suns. For that I have tried the following command:

```
wget -r -nd --accept-regex '.*(RMD)\d+\_+[A-Z][0-9]\.(TAB)' ftp://atmos.nmsu.edu/PDS/data/mslrem_1001/DATA/SOL_00001_00089/SOL00010/
```

The url is different just to try it. The problem is that wget ignores the regex expression and downloads all the files but I don't know why.

Comment: This was a bug, and was fixed in wget 1.19.4 https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=53750

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something simpler:

`wget -r -nd -A '*RMD*.TAB' ftp://atmos.nmsu.edu/PDS/data/mslrem_1001/DATA/`

Comment: Is there a solution which supports the regex? The glob here would match lots of files not matched by the regex above.

Answer (score 0):

You could try globbing instead of Regex. From [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#FTP-Options):

> `‘--no-glob’`
>
> Turn off FTP globbing. Globbing refers to the use of shell-like
>   special characters (wildcards), like ‘*’, ‘?’, ‘[’ and ‘]’ to retrieve
>   more than one file from the same directory at once, like:
>
> ```
> wget ftp://gnjilux.srk.fer.hr/*.msg
> ```
>
> By default, globbing will be turned on if the URL contains a globbing
>   character. This option may be used to turn globbing on or off
>   permanently.
>
> You may have to quote the URL to protect it from being expanded by
>   your shell. Globbing makes Wget look for a directory listing, which is
>   system-specific. This is why it currently works only with Unix FTP
>   servers (and the ones emulating Unix ls output).

Example:

```
wget -r -nd "ftp://atmos.nmsu.edu/PDS/data/mslrem_1001/DATA/*.TAB"
```