# wget regex options ignored over ftp

Tags: regular-expression, wget, ftp

Wget specifies the `--accept-regex` and `--reject-regex` options for limiting recursive downloads. I'm unable to get them to work with an ftp connection.

For example, I would expect `--reject-regex='.*'` to reject everything, but instead it downloads all files. Here is a public ftp site for testing with a few small files.

```
wget -r -nd --reject-regex='.*' 'ftp://ftp.rcsb.org/pub/pdb/data/status/20070425/'
```

Note that work arounds with `-A` (e.g. the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379922/wget-regex-fails-getting-files-over-ftp)) are not acceptable because I need to distinguish closely related filenames that differ by complex rules.

If wget does not support this over FTP, are there any other tools that can download files matching a regex over ftp?

Comment: This was a bug, and was fixed in wget 1.19.4 https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=53750